# Range of IP address to be allowed from internal network for Bluemix Containers

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

We cannot push any Docker Images to Bluemix registry as our Internal Proxy is blocking the requests to Bluemix domain. Our Network team needs the range of IP Addresses which they need to allow . Can you help with the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For connecting to the Container Service in Dallas you will need the following IP addresses:

169.46.9.7
169.46.9.19
169.46.9.24
169.46.9.28
169.55.211.15
169.55.211.17
169.55.211.21
169.55.211.28

And to be able to connect to the registry in Dallas, you will also need:

169.46.9.2
169.46.9.3
169.46.9.20
169.46.9.21
169.55.39.122
169.55.39.124
169.55.39.126
169.55.211.14

To connect to the Container Service in London, you will need the following IP addresses:

159.8.188.181
159.8.188.182
159.8.188.184
159.8.188.188
169.50.153.66
169.50.153.77
169.50.153.91
169.50.153.94

And for the London registry, you will need:

159.8.188.168
159.8.188.169
159.8.188.174
159.8.188.179
169.50.153.69
169.50.153.76
169.50.153.81
169.50.153.85

We are working on updating the documentation to provide this information.